# PHP project needs placement in www root-how to fix with .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, path, lamp

I have to work with several of someone else's PHP projects that have paths hard-coded in such a way that I have to put each project in my `/var/www/` directory one at a time to run it - instead of being able to it in its own subdirectory, like `/var/www/project_name`.

Is there some way to work around this so I don't have to put each project directly in my webroot directory?  Having to do that lets me only work with one project at a time with my local LAMP server!

**Edit:** For doing it the "VirtualHost" way, what would my `ServerName` be for `project_name`? I've tried just `project_name` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: OK, got it working with vhosts `project_name` after editing the right `hosts` file. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add

something like this to your `hosts` file

```
localproject1  127.0.0.1
localproject2  127.0.0.1
...
```

- In apache create a virtual server for each of them, each with their own webroot
  (and what could be more important) logfiles.
- browse to them via http://localproject1, http://localproject2, ...

Comment: Well..hadn't thought about using vhosts at all! Thanks, I'll give this a shot!

Comment: @Eugen: to quote `man 5 hosts` "For each host a single line should be present with the following information: `IP_address canonical_hostname [aliases...]`" in otherwords the correct syntax is `127.0.0.1 localhost localproject1 localproject2`, but the general recommendation is a good one.

Comment: The point that Eugen omits but implies is that you can assign separate document roots in each vhost config.

Comment: @TerryE I was WAMP in my head, not LAMP - sorry for that. And I wrote "each with their own webroot", which I thought would be clear

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have many options, if you want to use different URL's per project you need to edit your hosts file, enable NameVirtualHost and use VirtualHost.
The other way is by placing each project in /var/www/project_name and set the rewrite base in your .htaccess on each folder as follows, so you can use absolute URLs and the project won't break

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /var/www/project_name
```

Comment: If I understand right, with vhosts I'll have `http://localproject1` as my URL, and with the `.htaccess` way I'll have `http://localhost/project1`. It's just a matter of preference right?

Comment: @Alfonso - bad advice: read the [RewriteBase documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase). The argument is in URI namespace not file name space, so the base in this case should be "`/`" in `/var/www/.htaccess` and `/project_name` if in `/var/www/project_name/.htaccess`.

Comment: It's preference, I prefer using diferent URLs per project, so you are certain the website won't break if you move it to a different server. @TerryE Thanks, I'm always confused with that